# MySQL: how to transform this using INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to write this query with `INNER JOIN`s?

```
SELECT links.product_id AS entity_id, products.sku, links.`linked_product_id` AS     linked_entity_id, products2.`sku` AS linked_skus
FROM catalog_product_entity AS products,
    catalog_product_link AS links,
    catalog_product_entity AS products2
WHERE links.`product_id` = products.`entity_id`
    AND links.`linked_product_id` = products2.`entity_id`
```

Also, `catalog_product_link` has a column `type_id`, and I wanted to get only rows with `type_id` value `1` with `AND catalog_product_link.type_id = 1` condition at the end, but it doesn't work. How do I go about getting only records with `type_id=1`?

I'm having a problem where when I add `WHERE links.type_id=1` to the statement, the result comes out wrong. Everything under `product_id` is the same number (same entity_id/product_id), and everything under `sku` is NULL. `linked_product_id` and `linked_skus` are correct, though.

More information:

`catalog_product_entity`

```
| entity_id | sku | ... |
-------------------
|    1      | abc |     |
|    2      | qwe |     |
|    3      | yui |     |
```

`catalog_product_link`

```
| product_id (same as entity_id) | linked_product_id | type_id |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|               1                |         5         |    1    |
|               1                |         6         |    1    |
|               2                |         1         |    2    |
|               3                |         1         |    1    |
|               3                |         2         |    1    |
|               3                |         4         |    1    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like...

```
SELECT
    p.sku,
    l.product_id AS entity_id, l.linked_product_id AS linked_entity_id
FROM catalog_product_entity AS p
     INNER JOIN catalog_product_link AS l
         ON p.entity_id= l.product_id
WHERE l.type_id = 1
```

Comment: I made a quick edit to fix a typo. It works, except for `WHERE l.type_id=1`. I'm having the problem I was having.. I updated my post for more description. Have any idea why I get some numbers and NULL  values for those two columns?

Comment: I re-read your question and realized you were defining the catalog_product_entity table twice, I updated my answer/code, you should be fine with my updated post as it joins the catalog_product_entity table with the catalog_product_link table by product_id selecting only rows where type_id = 1. Let me know if that doesn't work or if you can post what your table contents look like currently it might paint a better picture.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what I did, but my original query with `AND links.link_type_id=1` appended at the end works fine now. But when I use yours, the returned records are like this [(NULL)|41891|66], [(NULL)|41891|67], [(NULL)|41891|68], [etc] (sku|entity_id|linked_entity_id). 41891 is one of the `entity_id`s but it's just repeated for all rows returned. This is the problem I was originally having.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   links.product_id AS entity_id, 
   products.sku, 
   links.linked_product_id AS linked_entity_id, 
   products2.sku AS linked_skus
FROM catalog_product_link AS links
INNER JOIN 
  catalog_product_entity AS products ON products.entity_id = links.product_id
INNER JOIN 
  catalog_product_entity AS products2 ON products2.entity_id = links.linked_product_id
WHERE links.type_id = 1
```